# How to check if a string is a valid PCRE?

Tags: php, regex

I need to check if a string is a valid regex.

Is there any way to do it without having performance issues?

N.B: I want to check it *BEFORE* using it, preg_last_error() is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested `preg_last_error` won't work for you because it only return PCRE runtime errors, not compilation faults - in the latter case all you get is a php warning ("Compilation failed"). A clean way to work around this is to install an [error-to-exception error handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php), and then compile the pattern within a try-catch block:

```
try {
    preg_match($pattern, "...");
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
   // something is wrong with the pattern 
}
```

Comment: If I don't find any _real_ solution to my problem, I'll accept your answer, as it's the _nicer_ one.

Comment: Well...I guess I'll stick with your answer for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is usually to just try and run/compile it with your Regex engine and check for errors. I wouldn't worry about performance before you need to.

Answer (score 0):

In php I'm using the following function to test the validity of a pcre:

```
function BoolTestPregRegex($Regex)
{
    $Result = @preg_match("/$Regex/", '1234567890123');

    if ($Result === false)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
```